# Data not recieving in rendered component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am navigating to View page(view.ts) after getting success from edit page *edit.ts*. While navigating to view page i am passing a boolean `isShowDialog = true` as input to *view.ts* but the value is not receiving in view page.

**edit.ts**

```
@Output() isShowDialog1 = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

editBusinessData(data) {
    let isShowDialog = true;
    ** some code missing **
    this.isShowDialog1.emit(isShowDialog);
    this.router.navigate(['/cloud/configuration/roomtypes/view']);
}
```

**view.ts**

```
@Input() isShowDialog;
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('view 41', this.isShowDialog);  //output view41 undefined
}
```

Comment: how you are passing from the component/

Comment: this.isShowDialog1.emit(isShowDialog); from edit.ts

Comment: thats how you pass output, try passing via component

Comment: thanks@Sajeetharan , could you tell me how to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the data in the route and then in the destination you can read that same data from the route. See also [Route parameters in the ActivatedRoute service](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service).

**edit.ts**

```
editBusinessData(data) {
    let isShowDialog = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/cloud/configuration/roomtypes/view', {isShowDialog: isShowDialog}]);
}
```

**view.ts**

```
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

    isShowDialog: boolean;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.isShowDialog = params.get('isShowDialog').toLower() === 'true';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Igor, will try and update you    hope it will fix my issue

Comment: it is working but, my PM told me dont show values in url        so i am using shared service to get the value of  ' isShowDialog '

Comment: @Santhosh - So I believe this probably should be marked as the answer then as you said it works but you are not using it because of a PM requirement that you did not state as a constraint in the question. Either way, I am glad you found something that works for you.